# Elegant way to add one row DataFrame to another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two `DataFrames` and one of them is a single row `DataFrame`. I want to add the one row `dataframe` across all the rows of the bigger one. I can solve it, but I am looking for a simpler solution:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'C':['car'],'D':['bus']})
print(df1)
     C    D
0  car  bus

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[8,2,0]})
print(df2)
   A  B
0  1  8
1  2  2
2  3  0
```

I want to join the line line DataFrame one across the bigger one. The result should be.

```
   A  B    C    D
0  1  8  car  bus
1  2  2  car  bus
2  3  0  car  bus
```

**My attempt:** I created a `dummy` column in both DataFrames and did a `left join`, but that's inelegant. I am sure there will be simpler solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the most elegant is use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), but is necessary strings columns names:

```
df2 = df2.assign(**df1.iloc[0])
print (df2)
   A  B    C    D
0  1  8  car  bus
1  2  2  car  bus
2  3  0  car  bus


df1.columns=[1,8]
print (df1)
     1    8
0  car  bus

df2 = df2.assign(**df1.iloc[0])
print (df2)
```

> TypeError: assign() keywords must be strings

Another solution working if match first index values:

```
df2 = df2.join(df1.reindex(df2.index, method='ffill'))
print (df2)
   A  B    C    D
0  1  8  car  bus
1  2  2  car  bus
2  3  0  car  bus
```